# Cloudkit JS Authentication fails using ionic inside ios device

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cloudkit

I am creating an ionic app for iPhone/iPad using cloudKit JS in order to storage data in cloud.
I try to authenticate to iCloud using cloudKit JS library. I had converted the Apple's Catalog sample - https://cdn.apple-cloudkit.com/cloudkit-catalog/ to iOS ionic app and Sign in button shows correctly and when press it, it opens a window popup in order to put apple credentials but after that nothing was happening there. Just a loader was displaying and it does not closing and respond back to the app with the user details
When a try this in Safari it works fine.

I am using:
     ios: v9.3
     ionic: v1.7.14
     ionic ios: v4.0.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a problem with Content security policy and cordova-whitelist-plugin? You need to set those for mobile to be able to load external data.

Whitelist guide:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Content security policy section:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#content-security-policy